# Can't seem to get jquery $.load to work

Tags: jquery

```
$(function() {
    $("#delete").click(function() {
        var r= confirm("Are you sure you want to delete these servers?");
        if(r == true){
                var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
                for (var i=0, iLen=inputs.length; i<iLen; i++) {
                if (inputs[i].type == 'checkbox'){
                    if(inputs[i].checked && inputs[i].name != "checkall"){
                        $("#modifyserver").load("deleteserver.php?ip=" + inputs[i].name);
                    }
                }
            }
            document.location.reload(true)
        }
    });
});
```

Above is my code.. I can't seem to get it working. It just won't load the page but if I put an alert into the if statment, it says it alerts me. Meaning, the `$("#modifyserver").load("deleteserver.php?ip=" + inputs[i].name);` is the part that isn't working.

Comment: What happens when you go to `deleteserver.php?ip=whatever` in a browser?

Comment: You're reloading the page during the ajax call.  Any reason for that?

Comment: logic is flawed,  each `load` will overwrite previous `load` and `document.location.reload` defeats purpose of ajax

Comment: On the page it is just running a mysql_query .. its supposed to be reloaded. I know the MySQL works, and I reload the page afterwards to visually see the changes.

Comment: Even if it the ajax did leave (which it does not), the reload request may come before the ajax request, missing its changes.

Comment: You should reload only _after_ the AJAX response is received

Comment: You are writing the results of multiple ajax calls to the same element, which would overwrite the previous results (only the last one would show). But you probably can't see this anyway, because you're reloading the page.

Comment: It isn't the reload, it isn't working when I remove it. It also doesn't work when I open it up in different divs.

Comment: how do you know it's not a server issue?

Comment: This may sound basic, but do you have an element with `id="modifyserver"` somewhere on your page?